# rails 3.2: Bluedot menu is not displaying in IE 8 but displaying in chrome and firefox

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-3.2, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

As intuit documentation suggested, here is my `application.html.erb` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ipp="">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script>
      intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({menuProxy: '<%= bluedot_settings_url %>', grantUrl: "<%= authenticate_settings_url %>"});
    </script>
    <% if signed_in? && current_company.access_token.present? && current_company.access_secret.present? && current_company.realm_id.present? %>
      <ipp:blueDot></ipp:blueDot>
    <% end %>
   </head>

   <body> 
     <%= yield%> 
   </body>
</html>
```

**PROBLEM IS:**
bluedot menu is displaying in browsers like: `chrome`, `firefox`, etc but It is not displaying in `Internet Explorer 8 (IE 8)`.

As you can see in my source code I have already included:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ipp="">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

What I am missing here, please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We support IE9 and above for our widgets but there have been some issues with widgets on IE and our engineering team is working on it.

Please verify your settings against the sample app from Intuit and see if it works for an IE9 browser. https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/